# Instagram Stories, how do they detect @username?

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api, snapchat

I have been using Instagram stories lately and they have such an incredible feature where in a picture/snap you can mention another user such as `@username` wherever you want in the picture and when you are viewing it you can click on that username and a pop-up lets you click into it. Similarly, they let you post a location.

If you are familiar with Stories you can write on an image anywhere and post that. So I am wondering how did they manage to do this? Do they perform image rec on the snap when viewing it and look for text? Or do they save the location in the image where that was posted and link it to data? Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

Instagram stories work same as any other Instagram photos or Facebook photos. When you are tagging a friend in an Instagram story the text gets written on the photo. At the same time there will be external tag on the story letting you to click the photo so it redirects you the mentioned profile. It is all in the code.